# Blank initial row when scraping and parsing BeautifulSoup TR:TD table

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, beautifulsoup

When I parse the a `<tr>/<td>` table in beautiful soup, the first row is always blank. Is there a way to get rid of this easily?

**Current code:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
for row in soup.select('tr'):
    text_columns = [td.a.get_text(strip=True) if td.a else td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    print(text_columns)
```

**Current output:**

```
[]
['date 1', 'details 1', 'amount 1', '', 'balance 1']
['date 2', 'details 2', 'amount 2', '', 'balance 2']
[etc....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see `soup.select('tr')` returns a `list` so you can do something like this: `for row in soup.select('tr')[1:]:` starting from second element.

The full code would be:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
for row in soup.select('tr')[1:]:
    text_columns = [td.a.get_text(strip=True) if td.a else td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    print(text_columns)
```